# What column size(varchar datatype) is needed to store an image in STRING format?

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to store an image in my SQLITE db. I checked out the length of the image's string with this code:

```
String res;
int reslen;
Log.i("asd", "doinback");
WebServiceConnecting wbs = new WebServiceConnecting();
res=wbs.SoapAction(new String[] {"FileName"}, new String[] {"1.jpg"}); //gets the image in string format
reslen=res.length();
res=String.valueOf(reslen);
Log.i("string res=",res );
```

I got the value of reslen as ~300,000. so what size should i give for my varchar column in SQLite db?

Comment: It should be of BLOB type. However, I do not recommend this. Find another way to save your images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK sqlite uses charset conversation for TEXT columns, consider using BLOB type to store image.

Comment: so does BLOB have any size restrictions? I ll have to store images of the size around 1MB.

Comment: Size is limited to 2147483647 bytes. Also, you can use external BLOB store to achieve performance: http://www.sqlite.org/intern-v-extern-blob.html

Comment: Thanks a lot Anton!! lemme check it out

Answer (score 0):

support a string or BLOB length up to 231-1 or 2147483647

Check further in
http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html

Comment: any way it's not wise idea, to store image as string